# Access Wamp 3.2.3 Virtualhost from another local pc

Tags: wampserver, wamp64

So I am trying to access a virtual host called myproject I have given it a server name... The issue is that I can access the Wampserver 3.2.3 interface from a external pc using the server's local ip address. Then if I click on the virtual host that I am trying to access it says "Could not connect"

I have edited the following in the hosts of the local pc

```
192.168.10.129 Servername
```

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
    ServerName floki
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried changing the 127.0.0.5 to a * but with no success. If someone can please help as soon as possible as I have hit a brick wall.

Please note that I am using wampserver 3.2.3 There is not put online or $suppress_localhost in index.php

Comment: In the other PC (not wampserver pc) place `192.168.10.129 floki` in the HOSTS file. That assumes that the PC running WAMPServer is on ip `192.168.10.129`

Comment: Also change `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>` back to the original `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: I did try both, but both failed

Answer (score 0):

it's may be late, but it could help someone else!
I think you should change the flag AllowOverride from None to All.